# jQuery - How to .show() & .hide() an element based on variable value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am creating a image slider from scratch as a bit of practice but I can't seem to overcome this problem. My four images are lined up next to each other and all .animate() to move to the next image using button clicks for forward and back.

Of course I don't want the user to press the forward & back buttons more than 4 times because they will then be presented with an empty slot where an image is supposed to be. I have a variable that increments/decrements each time I click and when it gets to more than or equal to 3/-3 I want the button to .hide() so it can't be clicked, and reappear once the value decreases/increases by the opposite button click. My code:

```
<code>$(document).ready(function() {
    var $clickcount = 0;    //clicks of forward/prev counter

 $('#forwardbtn').click(function() {        //forward button clicked..

    $clickcount ++;     //increment clickcount +1
    $('#sliderimg1, #sliderimg2, #sliderimg3, #sliderimg4').animate(
    {left:'+=950px'}, 800,'easeInOutQuad');   

    if($clickcount >= 3 ) {     //if clickcount = 3
        $('#forwardbtn').hide();    //hide button so it cant be clicked
    } else {
        $('#forwardbtn').show(); }  //otherwise keep it shown..
 });

 $('#prevbtn').click(function() {   //function opposite of one above

    $clickcount --;
    $('#sliderimg1, #sliderimg2, #sliderimg3, #sliderimg4').animate(
    {left:'-=950px'}, 800,'easeInOutQuad');

    if($clickcount >= -3 ) {
        $('#prevbtn').hide();
    } else {
        $('#prevbtn').show(); }
 });    
 });</code>
```

Any help appriciated, thanks for your time :)

Comment: What is your problem? What is it doing?

Comment: What's the problem you're having?  Also check out jQuery's `toggle` method: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display

Comment: The prev/forward buttons don't come back into view when the variables value decreases.

Comment: you have to do a function call on each click to check values

Comment: `if($clickcount >= -3 )` should be `if($clickcount <= -3 )` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at example in **[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dnoxv34e/1/)**

Changing conditions for `forwardbtn` if egal 3 hide it else show the both because we are in (1st or 2nd) image. and for the `prevbtn` condition id if we the position egals zero we have to hide button because there's no image before the first image else we have to show the both.

**Full js :**

```
var $clickcount = 0;    //clicks of forward/prev counter

$('#forwardbtn').click(function() {        //forward button clicked..    
    $clickcount ++;     //increment clickcount +1
    $('#sliderimg1, #sliderimg2, #sliderimg3, #sliderimg4').animate(
    {left:'+=950px'}, 800,'easeInOutQuad');

    if($clickcount == 3 ) {     //if clickcount = 3
        $('#forwardbtn').hide();    //hide button so it cant be clicked
    } else {
        $('#forwardbtn').show(); 
        $('#prevbtn').show();
    }  //otherwise keep it shown..
});

$('#prevbtn').click(function() {   //function opposite of one above
    $clickcount --;

    $('#sliderimg1, #sliderimg2, #sliderimg3, #sliderimg4').animate(
    {left:'-=950px'}, 800,'easeInOutQuad');

    if($clickcount == 0 ) {
        $('#prevbtn').hide();
    } else {
        $('#prevbtn').show(); 
        $('#forwardbtn').show(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments, they all helped a lot!

Comment: Sorry man, I don't disagree with you but I'm new to this website really so I just upvoted what I could. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Both checks on `clickcount` should be done in both click handler otherwise if `clickcount = 3` and back button is clicked the forward button is not shown back

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $clickcount = 0;    //clicks of forward/prev counter

  $('#forwardbtn').click(function() {        //forward button clicked..

    $clickcount ++;     //increment clickcount +1
    $('#sliderimg1, #sliderimg2, #sliderimg3, #sliderimg4').animate(
      {left:'+=950px'}, 800,'easeInOutQuad');   

    if($clickcount >= 3 ) {     //if clickcount = 3
      $('#forwardbtn').hide();    //hide button so it cant be clicked
    } else {
      $('#forwardbtn').show(); 
    }  //otherwise keep it shown..
    if($clickcount <= -3 ) {
      $('#prevbtn').hide();
    } else {
      $('#prevbtn').show(); 
    }

  });

  $('#prevbtn').click(function() {   //function opposite of one above

    $clickcount --;
    $('#sliderimg1, #sliderimg2, #sliderimg3, #sliderimg4').animate(
      {left:'-=950px'}, 800,'easeInOutQuad');

    if($clickcount <= -3 ) {
      $('#prevbtn').hide();
    } else {
      $('#prevbtn').show(); 
    }
    if($clickcount >= 3 ) {     //if clickcount = 3
      $('#forwardbtn').hide();    //hide button so it cant be clicked
    } else {
      $('#forwardbtn').show(); }  //otherwise keep it shown..
    });
  });
```

Comment: why we have to check in the both click handler ?? checking clickcount  one time in every click is enough.

Comment: Imagine this scenario: `clickcount = 3` so forward button is hidden. User clicks on back button, so `clickcount = 2`. You need to show again the forward button and you have to do that in the back button handler because is the only one that is executed. Same situation when `clickcount = -3` and user press forward button

Comment: Check my answer please, you have just to add show() of forward in the other side...